# Xaml Variable in a Textblock

Tags: powershell, xaml, variables, string-interpolation, quoting

Learning PowerShell, I was suggested to solve an issue with Xaml. Not knowing Xaml at all, I was able to build a window the way I expect it to be for a private project of mine.

Playing around with Xaml and the below code, I was able to generate a Window and place a table in it. The idea is for later, that a loop will build the Table and so far that is also running.

```
Clear-Host
$Test = "Vocabulary Test Results"

$AnotherTest = '<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="28" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="$Test" />  <Separator />'

#Load Assembly and Library
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$Form = @"
<Window 


    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  




    Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000">  

     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">  

      <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">  

        $AnotherTest

      <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Question Nr:" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Asked Question" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Expected Answer" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Your Answer" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Result" />



    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Button 5</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">Button 6</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2">Button 7</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">Button 8</Button>


</Grid>

</StackPanel>  
</ScrollViewer>  
</Window> 

"@

#Create a form
$XMLReader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$XMLForm = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($XMLReader)

#Show XMLform
[void]$XMLForm.ShowDialog()
```

The issue I am fighting now is with the line containing this code:

```
$AnotherTest = '<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="28" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="$Test" />  <Separator />'
```

I tried to add a variable behind "Text" but trying all kinds of things, I am not able to receive "Vocabulary Test Results" as text. Either I have an error messages or end up with with a blank field, or see the variable code and not the expected result.

I tried several ideas like

```
Text="$($Test")
Text=$Test
Text=""$Test""
Text={$Test}
```

and a few more. None of these did return the expected result.
Trying to find some solution online, I did see some binding examples but must admit, that I did not fully understand, how that works.

Is there an easy way to solve this or is there no way around bindings and if yes, how would I do that?

Thank you for any help and suggestions

Comment: Surround the entire value in double quotes to allow for string expansion. Then backtick escape the remaining inner double quotes. Here-string @“”@ could also work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. What does backtick escape the remaining inner double quotes mean?

Comment: hmmm, I tried the backtick: Text=(backtick)"$Text" and also Text=(backtick)"$Text"(backtick), so I must have misunderstood you, I have still error, sorry about that

Comment: strange, I tried your way and also tried (backtick)”value” (backtick) but no success. Additionally, I tried to put the backticks outside the quotes and also inside the quotes, but still having problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `"..."` quoting (double-quoting) is required in order for *variable references* (e.g. `$text`) or *subexpressions* (e.g., `$($text + '!')`) embedded in such a string to be *expanded* (interpolated), i.e., to be replaced with their value.

  - By contrast, the content of a `'...'` (single-quoted) string is interpreted *verbatim* - no expansion happens.
- If you need to *embed* literal `"` characters in a `"..."` string, you need to *escape* them (each), which can be done in one of two ways:

  - As `` `" ``, which is preferable, because `` ` `` generally acts as PowerShell's escape character; e.g.:

    - `` "Nat `"King`" Cole" ``
  - Alternatively, inside `"..."` only, you may use `""`.

    - `"Nat ""King"" Cole"`
- You can *avoid* the need for this escaping if you use an expandable *here-string* (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`), as you're already using to assign to the `$Form` variable; do note that the closing delimiter, `"@`, must be on its own line and at the *very start* of that line to be recognized.

See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).

Applied to your scenario:

- As an expandable string, with escaping:

```bsh
$AnotherTest = "<TextBlock FontWeight=`"Bold`" ... Text=`"$Test`" />  <Separator />"
```

- As an expandable *here-string*, without the need for escaping:

```bsh
$AnotherTest = @"
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="28" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="$Test" />  <Separator />
"@
```